# Won, two, fore, what is the next score?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Won plus won is two. Two plus Two is four. Fore plus fore is?
Hint: FSQ

Comment: Fore plus fore is ate

Comment: To plus To is Fore?

Comment: Very good answer, and I expected that people would post this one, but it's not the answer I was looking for and doesn't match the hint of FSQ. Thank you though!  Also appreciate the -5 votes! Guess this isn't my community. The answer was Quarterfinals, as the two quarters of fore and fore come before semis and the finals of the two teams that won. To plus to is also a good answer, rhssquared may have recognized the value of fore comes before.

Comment: @Michaeld Hello, please do not say the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Fore plus fore is

> ate

Because

> It is about homophones. 1 sounds like "one", 4 sounds like "fore", and 8 sounds like "ate"

So

> Fore (4) + Fore (4) = Ate (8)

Comment: Very good answer, and I expected that people would post this one, but it's not the answeet I was looking for and doesn't match the hint of FSQ. Thank you though!

Answer (score 2):

Fore plus four is

> **eight**

Because

> The pattern is, generally, (homophone) plus (homophone) is (actual number).
>  The exception is "Two plus Two is four." which I can't explain; it actually seems like an error that should have been "Too plus Too is four."

Comment: Very good answer, and I expected that people would post this one, but it's not the answeet I was looking for and doesn't match the hint of FSQ. Thank you though!